# Unable to call a function when a node is checked/unchecked in JStree

Tags: jstree

I have a requirement to perform a recursive action whenever a node is checked/unchecked in JStree. 
I tried to do the following, but the function is never invoked. How should I call a function from JStree on checking/unchecking a node?

```
 $('#jstree').on("uncheck_node.jstree", function (e, data)
{
subfunction(selectednodetouncheck, data); 
};

function subfunction(para1, para2)
{
//some operation; 
};
```

The subfunction is never called.... Please let me know how to call this function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select_node` and `deselect_node` as below. If you want to check and select a node separately, you need to set the `tie_selection` param of checkbox plugin in the tree config as false and select/deselect a node manually.

Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/y7jsLr3x/)

```
$("#jstree")
    .jstree({
        core: {
            data: coredata,
            check_callback: true
        },
        plugins: ["checkbox"],
        checkbox: {
            tie_selection: false
        }
    })
    .on("select_node.jstree deselect_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
        subfunction(data);
    })
    .on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
        subfunction2(data);
    });

function subfunction(data) {
    //some operation;
    alert('You got me selected: ' + data.node.state.selected)
};

function subfunction2(data) {
    //some operation;
    alert('You got me checked: ' + data.node.state.checked);

   //  now you need to decide what you want to select or not
   // and do it manually, e.g. like below
    var selectFlag = true; 

    if (selectFlag) {
        var action = data.node.state.checked ? 'select_node' : 'deselect_node';
        $("#jstree").jstree(action, data.node);
    }

};
```

Comment: But is it an ideal way? select_node is different from check_node. what if there is separate function for select_node i.e. on selecting a node - it should perform something and check_node it should perform something else.

Comment: If you want to have it separately, you will have to manually select/deselect a node after it was checked/unchecked. And you will need to specify that you want to untie selecting a node from checking in the checkbox plugin config - I updated my answer and demo.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I was doing a mistake with the parameters to invoke the function.  $('#jstree').on("uncheck_node.jstree", function (e, data)
{
subfunction(data.node.id); 
}; //invokes the function